# How to print error instead of showing the html?

Tags: php, html, error-handling

So I have a simple `index.php` code

```
<? php
    $number = $_GET['number']

    if (is_int($number) == FALSE) {
        // Don't show the below html, instead only show "ERROR: Expected a number"
    } else {
        $number = $number * 2 * 3 +1;
    }

    $number = $number - 10;
    // do some other php stuff here
?>

<html>
    <header>
        <title>Numbers are fun</title>
    </header>
    <u>Welcome to my cool website</u><br>
    <b>If you like numbers, you'll love this website!</b><br>
    <b>Your number is <?php echo $number ?></b>

    <footer>
        <br><br><b>This is the footer!!!</b>
    </footer>
</html>
```

My question is, I have html below the php code, so how can I stop that from printing if the string entered by the user is not an int? I know I can echo the HTML in the php, but that looks messy in the code.

Comment: Not a fan of it but you can do exit('Expecting it to be a number') or die('Expecting it to be a number') in php to print your thing and exit

Comment: @rs007 So it will not show any of the html?

Comment: yeah it will output your message and terminate the current script: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Solution:

```
    <? php
        $number = $_GET['number']

        if (is_int($value) == FALSE) {
            // Don't show the below html, instead only show "ERROR: Expected a number"
        } else {
    ?>

    <html>
    <header>
        <title>Numbers are fun</title>
    </header>
    <u>Welcome to my cool website</u><br>
    <b>If you like numbers, you'll love this website!</b><br>
    <b>Your number is <?php echo $number ?></b>

    <footer>
        <br><br><b>This is the footer!!!</b>
    </footer>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

You could also put the PHP inside the HTML, to avoid duplicating the outer HTML structure. Something like:

```
<html>
<header>
    <title>Numbers are fun</title>
</header>
<u>Welcome to my cool website</u><br>
<b>If you like numbers, you'll love this website!</b><br>
<? php
    $number = $_GET['number']

    if (is_int($value) == FALSE) {
        // Don't show the below html, instead only show "ERROR: Expected a number"
        ?><b>An error occurred</b><?php 
    } else { ?>
        <b>Your number is <?php echo $number ?></b>
    <?php }
?>

<footer>
    <br><br><b>This is the footer!!!</b>
</footer>
```

Comment: What if I have code under the if statement? I have updated the original code

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect another possibility. The great thing about PHP is how flexible the tags are, you can open and close PHP wherever you need to.

Comment: If I do it the second way (where the file extension is .html) I can use the url format of `www.domain.com/index.php?number=123`

Comment: If you're using PHP in the file, you should use .php as the file extension (you can configure your web server to allow you to do otherwise, but it's unnecessary complexity)

Comment: I think I explained it badly. basically, I want the input by the user to always be in the url. Hence `index.php?number=123`. Also the second example still shows all the html. If the input is not a number then the only thing shown is the error message

Comment: If the input is put in the URL (via a form or some other method) then it will stay there unless you send the user to another URL or they navigate elsewhere.

Comment: If you don't want to print any HTML in the case of an error, then you could either use the first option I suggested, or use exit() or die() as suggested in the comments to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php
    $number = $_GET['number'];

    if (is_int($number) == FALSE) {
        exit('Expecting the entered number to be an integer');
    } else {
        $number = $number * 2 * 3 +1;
    }

    $number = $number - 10;
    // do some other php stuff here
?>

<html>
    <header>
        <title>Numbers are fun</title>
    </header>
    <u>Welcome to my cool website</u><br>
    <b>If you like numbers, you'll love this website!</b><br>
    <b>Your number is <?php echo $number; ?></b>

    <footer>
        <br><br><b>This is the footer!!!</b>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: ..Oh, I retract previous comment. So what did you change here? Answers should have explanations. `You can try this` is not an answer, it will not explain to any future visitor what was changed or why.

Comment: I have added exit('Expecting the entered number to be an integer'); to the above code.

Answer (score 0):

We can use html code inside php code by **echo** statement

For not making messy in the code you can use this online tool to convert HTML code to PHP code

https://codebeautify.org/html-to-php-converter

```
<? php
$number = $_GET['number']

if (is_int($number) == FALSE) {
    // Don't show the below html, instead only show "ERROR: Expected a number"
    print_r("ERROR: Expected a number")
} else {
    $number = $number * 2 * 3 +1;

    echo '<html>';
    echo '<header>';
    echo '<title>Numbers are fun</title>';
    echo '</header>';
    echo '<u>Welcome to my cool website</u><br>';
    echo '<b>If you like numbers, you'll love this website!</b><br>';
    echo '<b>Your number is <?php echo $number ?></b>';
    echo '';
    echo '<footer>';
    echo '<br><br><b>This is the footer!!!</b>';
    echo '</footer>';
    echo '</html>';
}

$number = $number - 10;
?>
```

Another method is

```
<? php
$number = $_GET['number']

if (is_int($number) == FALSE) {
    print_r("ERROR: Expected a number")
} else {
?>
<html>
<header>
    <title>Numbers are fun</title>
</header>
<u>Welcome to my cool website</u><br>
<b>If you like numbers, you'll love this website!</b><br>
<b>Your number is <?php echo $number ?></b>

<footer>
    <br><br><b>This is the footer!!!</b>
</footer>
</html>
<?php 
    $number = $number * 2 * 3 +1;
}

$number = $number - 10;
// do some other php stuff here
?>
```